# How to add printer to Active Directory in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, active-directory, printer, windows-server-2016

I have a few printers which I can view in Print Management. I have enabled in two of them "List in Directory" option, but they don't appear under Active Directory Users and Computers. Where exactly should they appear when I check "List in Directory" option? How can I make them appear in Active Directory Users and Computers, so that I can move them into appropriate OU that I want?

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious nor intuitive.

In ADUC from the menu bar select **View... Users, Contacts, Groups and Computers as containers** then find the print server in the left pane, select it and you'll see the printer as a "sub-object" of the computer object in the right pane.

[image]